# iOS custom object initialization Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, custom-object

I have a custom object `ProductCategory`.

.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ProductCategory : NSObject

@property int productCategoryId;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSArray *children;
@property int parentCategoryId;


- (id)initWithId:(int)productCategoryId name:(NSString*)name;

- (id)initWithId:(int)productCategoryId name:(NSString*)name children:(NSArray*)chidren parentCategoryId:(int)parentCategoryId;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ProductCategory.h"

@implementation ProductCategory

- (id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.parentCategoryId = 0;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithId:(int)productCategoryId name:(NSString*)name {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
        self.name = name;
        self.parentCategoryId = 0;
    }

    return self;
}


- (id)initWithId:(int)productCategoryId name:(NSString*)name children:(NSArray*)chidren parentCategoryId:(int)parentCategoryId {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
        self.name = name;
        self.children = chidren;
        self.parentCategoryId = parentCategoryId;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

It's just a normal object, I have done this 100000 times. The problem is, sometimes the instance of this object returns `"0 objects"` and sometimes returns the correct object.

For example, if I do this `ProductCategory *category = [[ProductCategory alloc]init];` sometimes it returns a `ProductCategory` instance, and sometimes it returns `"0 objects"` so I cannot assign any value to this object.

[image]

I guess it should be something really stupid but I don't see it.

Comment: I just created an empty project with just your code, and it seems to be working perfectly.. Maybe the error is elsewhere ?

Comment: i didn't see errors on your code, try setup breakpoints on constructors, what you call, and how? i thing errors is on above level.

Comment: The weird thing is sometimes it works and sometimes not. For example, when I restart my computer, the first time I run the app it works, but after 1-2 times it doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: I think It´s good idea to add, your overrider init to the header (.h) file. Add in the header file: -(id)init;

Comment: I have set a breakpoint on the empty constructor and `self` returns `0 objects`...

Comment: Don't rely on the debugger.  Either use NSLog or stop at a breakpoint and type "po category" in the console window.

Comment: Also, remember that if you have a local variable as an object pointer with no subsequent references, ARC will delete the object pointed to pretty much immediately.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks, you are right, i can see the variable values typing  "po category" but it doesn't make any sense, this only happens to this object, if I create any other object I can see it on the debugger...it's a bit weird, isn't it?

Comment: The debugger is weird.  It's so untrustworthy that I rarely use it.

Comment: Also getting this - if you found a solution, would love to hear it!

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't find a solution yet, the debugger it's just not working only for that object :(

Comment: @Ale I have exactly the same Problem. Did you solve it yet?

Answer (score 4):

**The way to fix it:**

Restart XCode.

**Why it happen?:**

Apple should answer this question.

It seems a garbage in memory issue after a period of time using XCode.

**Workarounds if you get trap there**

@HotLicks is right about the advising of use `NSLog` and `po` to be sure about the state of that object.

Also you can invoke methods and read properties of the object in question by using `expression` command in debugger window after a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

zevarito is on the right track. A bit more seems to solve the long-irritating problem:

Close the project.

Xcode -> Window -> Projects
For the project in question (and all others is probably a good housecleaning idea), click Derived Data -> Delete.

Close Xcode.
Close Simulator.

Restart Xcode and resume what you were doing.